# How to split Address String in Python?

Tags: python

I'm reading data from excel trying to split this address string into variables but I cant split the Apartment # from the city and help?

When I read from my excel file I get this `strAddress = row[11]`  in Python:

```
5555 Fat Drive
# 6
Broken Bow, OK   74728
5555 Farmers Mill Rd
Garvin, OK   74736
```

When I split this with a comma `strAddress.split(',')` I get:

```
['5555 Fat Drive\n# 6\nBroken Bow', ' OK   74728']
['5555 Farmer Mill Rd\nGarvin', ' OK   74736']
```

When I split `strAddr1 = strAddress.split('\n')[0]` I get:

```
5555 Fat Drive
5555 Farmer Mill Rd
```

I want to be able to get the second address such as #6 without capturing the city name any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the address into lines. If the address has an apartment number, there will be 3 lines, and the apartment will be in the second line.

```
lines = strAddress.split('\n')
if len(lines) == 3:
    apartment = lines[1]
else:
    apartment = ''
```

Comment: Hey with this way how can I get the City and State and Zip?  @Barmar

Comment: A regular expression would probably be easiest. `^([^,]+)\s*(\w{2})\s+(\d+(?:-\d+))$`

Comment: Instead of the '\n' ? It didn't work for me @Barmar

Comment: No, that's how you parse the last line, which is `lines[-1]`

Comment: `match = re.search(above_regex, lines[-1])`.